# Ubuntu 14.04.3 server both a free-radius server and an active directory server

Tags: networking, radius

Can you make an Ubuntu 14.04.3 server both a free-radius server and an active directory server? I want to use the same server for both authentication and radius to have our access points use the radius authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out your really don't need to do anything because the AD is on the server. I was trying to join to my server to itself with net join. All you need to do is skip that step and use **`ntlm_auth --request-nt-key --domain=ADDomain --username=user --password=password`** to test it out.